# Relation between the modules of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I have the following main equations:
$$
\bar{y}^{ini}= \bar{x_a}^{ini} - \bar{x_b}^{ini} \\\\
\bar{y}^{fin}= \bar{x_a}^{fin} - \bar{x_b}^{fin} \\\\
$$

Where,
$$
\bar{y}^{ini} = {y}^{ini}\angle \phi^{ini} \\\\
\bar{y}^{fin} = {y}^{fin}\angle \phi^{fin} \\\\
\bar{x_a}^{ini} = {x_a}^{ini}\angle {\theta_a}^{ini} \\\\
\bar{x_a}^{fin} = {x_a}^{fin}\angle {\theta_a}^{fin} \\\\
\bar{x_b}^{ini} = {x_b}^{ini}\angle {\theta_b}^{ini} \\\\
\bar{x_b}^{fin} = {x_b}^{fin}\angle {\theta_b}^{fin} \\\\
$$

These variable are written in the polar form.

Then I define the following variables:
$$
\Delta {x_a} = {x_a}^{fin} - {x_a}^{ini} \\\\
\Delta {x_b} = {x_b}^{fin} - {x_b}^{ini} \\\\
\Delta {y} = {y}^{fin} - {y}^{ini} \\\\
$$

Base on the main equations, is it possible to get a equations that relates: $\Delta {y}$, $\Delta {x_a}$ and $\Delta {x_b}$?, that is, something like: $\Delta {y} = f(\Delta {x_a},\Delta {x_b})$. I am interested in getting a relation between: $\Delta {y}$, $\Delta {x_a}$ and $\Delta {x_b}$, even though some simplifications or approximations are applied.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

---

What I have done so far:

Option one: First take the absolute in the two equations and then subtract.

$$
|\bar{y}^{fin}|- |\bar{y}^{ini}|= |\bar{x_a}^{fin} - \bar{x_b}^{fin}| - |\bar{x_a}^{ini} - \bar{x_b}^{ini} | \\\\
{y}^{fin}- {y}^{ini}= |\bar{x_a}^{fin} - \bar{x_b}^{fin}| - |\bar{x_a}^{ini} - \bar{x_b}^{ini} | \\\\
\Delta {y}= |\bar{x_a}^{fin} - \bar{x_b}^{fin}| - |\bar{x_a}^{ini} - \bar{x_b}^{ini} | \\\\
$$

But then, I am stuck and dont know how to proceed with the absolute operators of the right side equation.

Option two: First subtract, and then see

$$
\bar{y}^{fin}- \bar{y}^{ini}= \bar{x_a}^{fin} - \bar{x_b}^{fin} - (\bar{x_a}^{ini} - \bar{x_b}^{ini} ) \\\\
\bar{y}^{fin}- \bar{y}^{ini}= \bar{x_a}^{fin} - \bar{x_a}^{ini} - (\bar{x_b}^{fin} - \bar{x_b}^{ini} ) \\\\
$$

And then I am again stuck and dont know how to proceed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, yes, it is the polar form. As an intermediate process, one could write it as $ z=x+iy$, but at the end I am interested in knowing the relation between the modules of those complex numbers. "ini" and "fin" is to indicate the initial and final state of those variables.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, yes, I meant relation between the difference of the modules, that is, $\Delta y, \Delta x_a, \Delta x_b$

Comment: So we don't need any $\angle \phi$ then? This would make the computation much shorter when we just look at the lenghts. So no need to introduce all "bar" variables, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, exactly, I would like to get rid of the angles if possible.

Comment: But this is easy. Just take only the part $r$ of $z=re^{i\phi}$ in the polar form, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), in the section on complex numbers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, sorry, but I dont see how using that form would change the problem. I would basically be in the same situation as the "option two" of my post, where I cannot move forward to get a relation of $\Delta y, \Delta x_a, \Delta x_b$

Comment: @BurNor No, it is not possible, because $\Delta {y}$ is not a function of $\Delta {x_a}$ and $\Delta {x_b}$, which in turn is because given complex numbers $a,b,c$ such that $a = b - c$ it is not possible to calculate $|a|$ based on $|b|,|c|$ alone.

Comment: @dxiv I actually saw in a paper that based on the main equations, this equation was written: $\Delta {y}$=$\Delta {x_a}$ -$\Delta {x_b}$, with the assumption that the changes in the angles of $\bar{x_a}$ and $\bar{x_b}$ were small. But to me that assumption is not enough to end in that equation.

Comment: @BurNor Sorry, but it's hard to guess what the paper meant by that without seeing the full context.